# ioctl LOOP_SET_FD failed: Device or resource busy

Tags: linux, mount, android, ioctl

I'm trying to get Backtrack to run on my Droid DNA. I've been tweaking the script little by little but I still come up with the following. I changed the loop on it, and another program always seems to jump in front, or I still get the ioctl error, then running it again gives the loop device exists (it doesn't the first time). Any ideas?

> root@android:/sdcard/bt5 # sh bootbt
>   Loop device exists
>   **ioctl LOOP_SET_FD failed: Device or resource busy**
>   mount: No such file or directory
>   mount: No such file or directory
>   mount: No such file or directory
>   net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
>   chroot: can't execute '/bin/bash': No such file or directory
>   Shutting down BackTrack ARM For DNA
>   failed: No such file or directory
>   failed: No such file or directory
>   failed: No such file or directory
>   failed: Invalid argument
>   1|root@android:/sdcard/bt5 # losetup
>   /dev/loop7: 0 /data/app-asec/fahrbot.apps.screen.pro1-1.asec
>   root@android:/sdcard/bt5 #

Kernel does support looping. I found this out. Here's my modified boot script to start Backtrack:

> perm=$(id|cut -b 5)
>
> if [ "$perm" != "0" ];then echo "This Script Needs Root! Type : su";exit;fi
>
> mount -o remount,rw /dev/block/mmcblk0p5 /system
>   export kit=/sdcard/bt5
>   export bin=/system/bin
>   export mnt=/data/local/mnt
>   mkdir -p $mntcd /
>   export PATH=$bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/games:$PATH
>   export TERM=linux
>   export HOME=/root
>   if [ -b /dev/block/loop99 ]; then
>     echo "Loop device exists"
>   else
>     busybox mknod /dev/block/loop99 b 7 99
>   fi
>   
>   echo "SETTING UP LOOP DEVICE"
>   losetup /dev/block/loop99 /sdcard/bt5/bt5.img
>
> mount -o loop,noatime -t ext2 $kit/bt5.img $mnt
>   mount -t devpts devpts $mnt/dev/pts
>   mount -t proc proc $mnt/proc
>   mount -t sysfs sysfs $mnt/sys
>   busybox sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
>   echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > $mnt/etc/resolv.conf
>   echo "127.0.0.1 localhost bt5" > $mnt/etc/hosts
>   busybox chroot $mnt /bin/bash
>
> echo "Shutting down BackTrack ARM For DNA"
>   umount $mnt/dev/pts
>   umount $mnt/proc 
>   umount $mnt/sys 
>   umount $mnt
>   losetup -d /dev/block/loop99

Even with loop99, I still get ioctl LOOP_SET_FD failed: Device or resource busy

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! Had to attach the image file to a /dev/block/loopxxx THEN mount the /dev/block/loopxxx as an ext4 file system.

Full how-to I wrote http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2194237 just in case anyone needs help figuring out the same thing I did.